# Custom-positioned page number appears in arabic-indic numerals

Tags: page-numbering, arabic, eso-pic

I am using LaTeX (TeXmaker) to give format to an article in arabic and spanish (with some special characters to represent a transliteration of arabic text). I used [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=20380) solution to locate my page number in the place that I needed (both header and footer will be used for other information). As I began to introduce the text (alternating between arabic and spanish) the page number sometimes is shown in arabic-western numerals and sometimes in arabic-indic numerals, but I would like them to show always in arabic-western numerals.

Sometimes using \newpage solves the problem, but sometimes it does not, so I need a permanent solution.

I left some packages I use in the preamble of the NWE, but I'm not sure if they're part of the problem or not.

NWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel} %Spanish

\usepackage{arabtex} %Arabic

\usepackage{utf8} %Arabic
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Spanish

% Page number
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \setlength\unitlength{0.43in}%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1.4in\relax}%
    \makebox(1,-3)[rt]{\thepage}%
}}

% Helvetica
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{textcomp} % Transliteration
\usepackage{semtrans} % Transliteration

\begin{document}
\setarab 

\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
 وقول الله تعالى: `الْيَوْمَ أَكْمَلْتُ لَكُمْ دِينَكُمْ وَأَتْمَمْتُ عَلَيْكُمْ نِعْمَتِي وَرَضِيتُ لَكُمُ لْأِسْلامَ 
ادِيناً.' (المائدة: من الآية3)
\\وقوله تعالى: `قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي شَكٍّ مِنْ دِينِي فَلا أَعْبُدُ الَّذِينَ تَعْبُدُونَ مِنْ
 دُونِ اللَّهِ وَلَكِنْ أَعْبُدُ اللَّهَ الَّذِي يَتَوَفَّاكُمْ.' (يونس: من الآية140)
\\وقوله تعالى: `يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَآمِنُوا بِرَسُولِهِ يُؤْتِكُمْ كِفْلَيْنِ مِنْ رَحْمَتِهِ
 وَيَجْعَلْ لَكُمْ نُوراً تَمْشُونَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَحِيمٌ.' (الحديد: 28)
\end{arabtext}  
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non erat ut neque semper mattis. Aliquam rutrum sem sit amet purus imperdiet lacinia. Cras aliquet lorem nisl, sit amet varius turpis consectetur id. Nulla scelerisque nulla in cursus mattis. Quisque dignissim turpis ut nunc rhoncus, quis elementum arcu interdum. Phasellus ut justo congue neque sagittis ultricies vel ac lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae metus quis nibh dictum hendrerit ullamcorper sit amet sapien. Etiam tempor dui quis sapien tristique, a vulputate urna tristique. Nunc malesuada, ligula a tristique ullamcorper, quam ante bibendum mi, in ullamcorper felis ligula at ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eu eleifend nulla. Fusce est velit, dapibus quis augue hendrerit, pulvinar posuere arcu. Donec diam purus, varius nec tempus at, faucibus sed mauris.
\bigskip
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
 وقول الله تعالى: `الْيَوْمَ أَكْمَلْتُ لَكُمْ دِينَكُمْ وَأَتْمَمْتُ عَلَيْكُمْ نِعْمَتِي وَرَضِيتُ لَكُمُ لْأِسْلامَ 
ادِيناً.' (المائدة: من الآية3)
\\وقوله تعالى: `قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي شَكٍّ مِنْ دِينِي فَلا أَعْبُدُ الَّذِينَ تَعْبُدُونَ مِنْ
 دُونِ اللَّهِ وَلَكِنْ أَعْبُدُ اللَّهَ الَّذِي يَتَوَفَّاكُمْ.' (يونس: من الآية140)
\\وقوله تعالى: `يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَآمِنُوا بِرَسُولِهِ يُؤْتِكُمْ كِفْلَيْنِ مِنْ رَحْمَتِهِ
 وَيَجْعَلْ لَكُمْ نُوراً تَمْشُونَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَحِيمٌ.' (الحديد: 28)
\end{arabtext}  
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non erat ut neque semper mattis. Aliquam rutrum sem sit amet purus imperdiet lacinia. Cras aliquet lorem nisl, sit amet varius turpis consectetur id. Nulla scelerisque nulla in cursus mattis. Quisque dignissim turpis ut nunc rhoncus, quis elementum arcu interdum. Phasellus ut justo congue neque sagittis ultricies vel ac lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae metus quis nibh dictum hendrerit ullamcorper sit amet sapien. Etiam tempor dui quis sapien tristique, a vulputate urna tristique. Nunc malesuada, ligula a tristique ullamcorper, quam ante bibendum mi, in ullamcorper felis ligula at ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eu eleifend nulla. Fusce est velit, dapibus quis augue hendrerit, pulvinar posuere arcu. Donec diam purus, varius nec tempus at, faucibus sed mauris.
\bigskip
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
 وقول الله تعالى: `الْيَوْمَ أَكْمَلْتُ لَكُمْ دِينَكُمْ وَأَتْمَمْتُ عَلَيْكُمْ نِعْمَتِي وَرَضِيتُ لَكُمُ لْأِسْلامَ 
ادِيناً.' (المائدة: من الآية3)
\\وقوله تعالى: `قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي شَكٍّ مِنْ دِينِي فَلا أَعْبُدُ الَّذِينَ تَعْبُدُونَ مِنْ
 دُونِ اللَّهِ وَلَكِنْ أَعْبُدُ اللَّهَ الَّذِي يَتَوَفَّاكُمْ.' (يونس: من الآية140)
\\وقوله تعالى: `يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَآمِنُوا بِرَسُولِهِ يُؤْتِكُمْ كِفْلَيْنِ مِنْ رَحْمَتِهِ
 وَيَجْعَلْ لَكُمْ نُوراً تَمْشُونَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَحِيمٌ.' (الحديد: 28)
\end{arabtext}  
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non erat ut neque semper mattis. Aliquam rutrum sem sit amet purus imperdiet lacinia. Cras aliquet lorem nisl, sit amet varius turpis consectetur id. Nulla scelerisque nulla in cursus mattis. Quisque dignissim turpis ut nunc rhoncus, quis elementum arcu interdum. Phasellus ut justo congue neque sagittis ultricies vel ac lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae metus quis nibh dictum hendrerit ullamcorper sit amet sapien. Etiam tempor dui quis sapien tristique, a vulputate urna tristique. Nunc malesuada, ligula a tristique ullamcorper, quam ante bibendum mi, in ullamcorper felis ligula at ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eu eleifend nulla. Fusce est velit, dapibus quis augue hendrerit, pulvinar posuere arcu. Donec diam purus, varius nec tempus at, faucibus sed mauris.
\bigskip
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
 وقول الله تعالى: `الْيَوْمَ أَكْمَلْتُ لَكُمْ دِينَكُمْ وَأَتْمَمْتُ عَلَيْكُمْ نِعْمَتِي وَرَضِيتُ لَكُمُ لْأِسْلامَ 
ادِيناً.' (المائدة: من الآية3)
\\وقوله تعالى: `قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي شَكٍّ مِنْ دِينِي فَلا أَعْبُدُ الَّذِينَ تَعْبُدُونَ مِنْ
 دُونِ اللَّهِ وَلَكِنْ أَعْبُدُ اللَّهَ الَّذِي يَتَوَفَّاكُمْ.' (يونس: من الآية140)
\\وقوله تعالى: `يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَآمِنُوا بِرَسُولِهِ يُؤْتِكُمْ كِفْلَيْنِ مِنْ رَحْمَتِهِ
 وَيَجْعَلْ لَكُمْ نُوراً تَمْشُونَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَحِيمٌ.' (الحديد: 28)
\end{arabtext}  
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non erat ut neque semper mattis. Aliquam rutrum sem sit amet purus imperdiet lacinia. Cras aliquet lorem nisl, sit amet varius turpis consectetur id. Nulla scelerisque nulla in cursus mattis. Quisque dignissim turpis ut nunc rhoncus, quis elementum arcu interdum. Phasellus ut justo congue neque sagittis ultricies vel ac lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae metus quis nibh dictum hendrerit ullamcorper sit amet sapien. Etiam tempor dui quis sapien tristique, a vulputate urna tristique. Nunc malesuada, ligula a tristique ullamcorper, quam ante bibendum mi, in ullamcorper felis ligula at ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eu eleifend nulla. Fusce est velit, dapibus quis augue hendrerit, pulvinar posuere arcu. Donec diam purus, varius nec tempus at, faucibus sed mauris.
\bigskip
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
 وقول الله تعالى: `الْيَوْمَ أَكْمَلْتُ لَكُمْ دِينَكُمْ وَأَتْمَمْتُ عَلَيْكُمْ نِعْمَتِي وَرَضِيتُ لَكُمُ لْأِسْلامَ 
ادِيناً.' (المائدة: من الآية3)
\\وقوله تعالى: `قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي شَكٍّ مِنْ دِينِي فَلا أَعْبُدُ الَّذِينَ تَعْبُدُونَ مِنْ
 دُونِ اللَّهِ وَلَكِنْ أَعْبُدُ اللَّهَ الَّذِي يَتَوَفَّاكُمْ.' (يونس: من الآية140)
\\وقوله تعالى: `يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَآمِنُوا بِرَسُولِهِ يُؤْتِكُمْ كِفْلَيْنِ مِنْ رَحْمَتِهِ
 وَيَجْعَلْ لَكُمْ نُوراً تَمْشُونَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَحِيمٌ.' (الحديد: 28)
\end{arabtext}  
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non erat ut neque semper mattis. Aliquam rutrum sem sit amet purus imperdiet lacinia. Cras aliquet lorem nisl, sit amet varius turpis consectetur id. Nulla scelerisque nulla in cursus mattis. Quisque dignissim turpis ut nunc rhoncus, quis elementum arcu interdum. Phasellus ut justo congue neque sagittis ultricies vel ac lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae metus quis nibh dictum hendrerit ullamcorper sit amet sapien. Etiam tempor dui quis sapien tristique, a vulputate urna tristique. Nunc malesuada, ligula a tristique ullamcorper, quam ante bibendum mi, in ullamcorper felis ligula at ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eu eleifend nulla. Fusce est velit, dapibus quis augue hendrerit, pulvinar posuere arcu. Donec diam purus, varius nec tempus at, faucibus sed mauris.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output1]
[image: Output2]
[image: Output3]

Lists of files (don't know if necessary, but the "how to ask" seems to recommend it?)
[image: file list1]
[image: file list2]

---

**Edit1: More details.**
I don't use the fancyhdr for the page number because there is other information placed there. To avoid overcrowding my header I want to put the page-number at the left of the main body of the text. This is how a final page in my article looks like (I used package showframe to show you the layout I need):

[image: final look]

So I need to preserve *this* page-number position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried some magic with the [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package. This is it. I run the `pdflatex` engine.

**Update:** I am shifting page numbers using TeX dimensions. It doesn't affect the rest of the header information. I enclose a preview of the result with and without the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package.

```
% run: pdflatex mal-pages.tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel} %Spanish
\usepackage{arabtex} %Arabic
\usepackage{utf8} %Arabic
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Spanish

\ifx\relax
% The OP's try...
% Page number
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \setlength\unitlength{0.43in}%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1.4in\relax}%
    \makebox(1,-3)[rt]{\pagenumbering{arabic}\thepage}%
  }}
\fi

%\ifx\relax
% A new approach...
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{Title of the book\ldots}
\fancyhead[R]{%
   First name, Surname%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\headsep-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \kern\dimexpr\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth\relax
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\thepage}}}%
  }
%\fi


% Helvetica
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{textcomp} % Transliteration
\usepackage{semtrans} % Transliteration

\begin{document}
\setarab 

\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
 وقول الله تعالى: `الْيَوْمَ أَكْمَلْتُ لَكُمْ دِينَكُمْ وَأَتْمَمْتُ عَلَيْكُمْ نِعْمَتِي وَرَضِيتُ لَكُمُ لْأِسْلامَ 
ادِيناً.' (المائدة: من الآية3)
\\وقوله تعالى: `قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي شَكٍّ مِنْ دِينِي فَلا أَعْبُدُ الَّذِينَ تَعْبُدُونَ مِنْ
 دُونِ اللَّهِ وَلَكِنْ أَعْبُدُ اللَّهَ الَّذِي يَتَوَفَّاكُمْ.' (يونس: من الآية140)
\\وقوله تعالى: `يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَآمِنُوا بِرَسُولِهِ يُؤْتِكُمْ كِفْلَيْنِ مِنْ رَحْمَتِهِ
 وَيَجْعَلْ لَكُمْ نُوراً تَمْشُونَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَحِيمٌ.' (الحديد: 28)
\end{arabtext}  
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non erat ut neque semper mattis. Aliquam rutrum sem sit amet purus imperdiet lacinia. Cras aliquet lorem nisl, sit amet varius turpis consectetur id. Nulla scelerisque nulla in cursus mattis. Quisque dignissim turpis ut nunc rhoncus, quis elementum arcu interdum. Phasellus ut justo congue neque sagittis ultricies vel ac lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae metus quis nibh dictum hendrerit ullamcorper sit amet sapien. Etiam tempor dui quis sapien tristique, a vulputate urna tristique. Nunc malesuada, ligula a tristique ullamcorper, quam ante bibendum mi, in ullamcorper felis ligula at ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eu eleifend nulla. Fusce est velit, dapibus quis augue hendrerit, pulvinar posuere arcu. Donec diam purus, varius nec tempus at, faucibus sed mauris.
\bigskip
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
 وقول الله تعالى: `الْيَوْمَ أَكْمَلْتُ لَكُمْ دِينَكُمْ وَأَتْمَمْتُ عَلَيْكُمْ نِعْمَتِي وَرَضِيتُ لَكُمُ لْأِسْلامَ 
ادِيناً.' (المائدة: من الآية3)
\\وقوله تعالى: `قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي شَكٍّ مِنْ دِينِي فَلا أَعْبُدُ الَّذِينَ تَعْبُدُونَ مِنْ
 دُونِ اللَّهِ وَلَكِنْ أَعْبُدُ اللَّهَ الَّذِي يَتَوَفَّاكُمْ.' (يونس: من الآية140)
\\وقوله تعالى: `يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَآمِنُوا بِرَسُولِهِ يُؤْتِكُمْ كِفْلَيْنِ مِنْ رَحْمَتِهِ
 وَيَجْعَلْ لَكُمْ نُوراً تَمْشُونَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَحِيمٌ.' (الحديد: 28)
\end{arabtext}  
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non erat ut neque semper mattis. Aliquam rutrum sem sit amet purus imperdiet lacinia. Cras aliquet lorem nisl, sit amet varius turpis consectetur id. Nulla scelerisque nulla in cursus mattis. Quisque dignissim turpis ut nunc rhoncus, quis elementum arcu interdum. Phasellus ut justo congue neque sagittis ultricies vel ac lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae metus quis nibh dictum hendrerit ullamcorper sit amet sapien. Etiam tempor dui quis sapien tristique, a vulputate urna tristique. Nunc malesuada, ligula a tristique ullamcorper, quam ante bibendum mi, in ullamcorper felis ligula at ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eu eleifend nulla. Fusce est velit, dapibus quis augue hendrerit, pulvinar posuere arcu. Donec diam purus, varius nec tempus at, faucibus sed mauris.
\bigskip
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
 وقول الله تعالى: `الْيَوْمَ أَكْمَلْتُ لَكُمْ دِينَكُمْ وَأَتْمَمْتُ عَلَيْكُمْ نِعْمَتِي وَرَضِيتُ لَكُمُ لْأِسْلامَ 
ادِيناً.' (المائدة: من الآية3)
\\وقوله تعالى: `قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي شَكٍّ مِنْ دِينِي فَلا أَعْبُدُ الَّذِينَ تَعْبُدُونَ مِنْ
 دُونِ اللَّهِ وَلَكِنْ أَعْبُدُ اللَّهَ الَّذِي يَتَوَفَّاكُمْ.' (يونس: من الآية140)
\\وقوله تعالى: `يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَآمِنُوا بِرَسُولِهِ يُؤْتِكُمْ كِفْلَيْنِ مِنْ رَحْمَتِهِ
 وَيَجْعَلْ لَكُمْ نُوراً تَمْشُونَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَحِيمٌ.' (الحديد: 28)
\end{arabtext}  
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non erat ut neque semper mattis. Aliquam rutrum sem sit amet purus imperdiet lacinia. Cras aliquet lorem nisl, sit amet varius turpis consectetur id. Nulla scelerisque nulla in cursus mattis. Quisque dignissim turpis ut nunc rhoncus, quis elementum arcu interdum. Phasellus ut justo congue neque sagittis ultricies vel ac lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae metus quis nibh dictum hendrerit ullamcorper sit amet sapien. Etiam tempor dui quis sapien tristique, a vulputate urna tristique. Nunc malesuada, ligula a tristique ullamcorper, quam ante bibendum mi, in ullamcorper felis ligula at ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eu eleifend nulla. Fusce est velit, dapibus quis augue hendrerit, pulvinar posuere arcu. Donec diam purus, varius nec tempus at, faucibus sed mauris.
\bigskip
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
 وقول الله تعالى: `الْيَوْمَ أَكْمَلْتُ لَكُمْ دِينَكُمْ وَأَتْمَمْتُ عَلَيْكُمْ نِعْمَتِي وَرَضِيتُ لَكُمُ لْأِسْلامَ 
ادِيناً.' (المائدة: من الآية3)
\\وقوله تعالى: `قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي شَكٍّ مِنْ دِينِي فَلا أَعْبُدُ الَّذِينَ تَعْبُدُونَ مِنْ
 دُونِ اللَّهِ وَلَكِنْ أَعْبُدُ اللَّهَ الَّذِي يَتَوَفَّاكُمْ.' (يونس: من الآية140)
\\وقوله تعالى: `يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَآمِنُوا بِرَسُولِهِ يُؤْتِكُمْ كِفْلَيْنِ مِنْ رَحْمَتِهِ
 وَيَجْعَلْ لَكُمْ نُوراً تَمْشُونَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَحِيمٌ.' (الحديد: 28)
\end{arabtext}  
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non erat ut neque semper mattis. Aliquam rutrum sem sit amet purus imperdiet lacinia. Cras aliquet lorem nisl, sit amet varius turpis consectetur id. Nulla scelerisque nulla in cursus mattis. Quisque dignissim turpis ut nunc rhoncus, quis elementum arcu interdum. Phasellus ut justo congue neque sagittis ultricies vel ac lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae metus quis nibh dictum hendrerit ullamcorper sit amet sapien. Etiam tempor dui quis sapien tristique, a vulputate urna tristique. Nunc malesuada, ligula a tristique ullamcorper, quam ante bibendum mi, in ullamcorper felis ligula at ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eu eleifend nulla. Fusce est velit, dapibus quis augue hendrerit, pulvinar posuere arcu. Donec diam purus, varius nec tempus at, faucibus sed mauris.
\bigskip
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtext}
 وقول الله تعالى: `الْيَوْمَ أَكْمَلْتُ لَكُمْ دِينَكُمْ وَأَتْمَمْتُ عَلَيْكُمْ نِعْمَتِي وَرَضِيتُ لَكُمُ لْأِسْلامَ 
ادِيناً.' (المائدة: من الآية3)
\\وقوله تعالى: `قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي شَكٍّ مِنْ دِينِي فَلا أَعْبُدُ الَّذِينَ تَعْبُدُونَ مِنْ
 دُونِ اللَّهِ وَلَكِنْ أَعْبُدُ اللَّهَ الَّذِي يَتَوَفَّاكُمْ.' (يونس: من الآية140)
\\وقوله تعالى: `يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا اتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَآمِنُوا بِرَسُولِهِ يُؤْتِكُمْ كِفْلَيْنِ مِنْ رَحْمَتِهِ
 وَيَجْعَلْ لَكُمْ نُوراً تَمْشُونَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرْ لَكُمْ وَاللَّهُ غَفُورٌ رَحِيمٌ.' (الحديد: 28)
\end{arabtext}  
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non erat ut neque semper mattis. Aliquam rutrum sem sit amet purus imperdiet lacinia. Cras aliquet lorem nisl, sit amet varius turpis consectetur id. Nulla scelerisque nulla in cursus mattis. Quisque dignissim turpis ut nunc rhoncus, quis elementum arcu interdum. Phasellus ut justo congue neque sagittis ultricies vel ac lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae metus quis nibh dictum hendrerit ullamcorper sit amet sapien. Etiam tempor dui quis sapien tristique, a vulputate urna tristique. Nunc malesuada, ligula a tristique ullamcorper, quam ante bibendum mi, in ullamcorper felis ligula at ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eu eleifend nulla. Fusce est velit, dapibus quis augue hendrerit, pulvinar posuere arcu. Donec diam purus, varius nec tempus at, faucibus sed mauris.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, with+without the geometry package]

Comment: Sorry, but the page number position is not the one I need. Please refer to the first edit of my question for further information.

Comment: @lumiso Please see my update.

Comment: Works well, thank you! One more thing please, how can I get rid of the pagenumber in the footer? I erased `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` but it still appears, it only eliminated its style.

Comment: @lumiso Please try: `\fancyfoot[C]{}`

Comment: Solved! Too bad I can't vote up your answer.

Comment: @lumiso Please have no worries about that! Good luck with typesetting your document!